# Orbits form a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

A prominent example are the coadjoint orbits $O_x = \{Ad_u^*(x);u \in G\}$ where $x \in \mathfrak{g}$ and $G$ a Lie group with Adjoint map $Ad.$

Could anybody give me an easy argument why $O_x$ is a smooth manifold?

Answer (score 16):

It follows from a much more general fact: Whenever a Lie group $G$ acts smoothly on a smooth manifold $M$, its orbits are immersed smooth manifolds. This can be derived from the following observations:

1. For each $p\in M$, the isotropy group $G_p = \{g\in G: g\centerdot p=p\}$ is a closed subgroup of $G$.
2. The quotient space $G/G_p$ has a unique smooth manifold structure, and $G$ acts transitively on this smooth manifold by left multiplication.
3. The orbit map $\mathscr O_p\colon G\to M$ given by $\mathscr O_p(g) = g\centerdot p$ descends smoothly to the quotient $G/G_p$ to give a smooth map $F_p\colon G/G_p\to M$ that is a bijection from $G/G_p$ onto the orbit $G\centerdot p$.
4. The map $F_p$ is equivariant with respect to the left actions of $G$ on $G/G_p$ and $M$, and therefore it has constant rank.
5. Because it is a constant-rank injection, $F_p$ is a smooth immersion, and therefore its image $G\centerdot p$ is a smoothly immersed submanifold of $M$.

I don't know if this would qualify as an "easy argument," but it's based on standard facts from elementary differential geometry, most of which can be found in Chapter 21 of my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (2nd ed.).

Comment: But, in this case, aren't the coadjoint orbits *embedded* smooth submanifolds?

Comment: @AlexZorn: Not necessarily, if $G$ is noncompact. There's an example due to Kirillov (cited in _Introduction to Mechanics and Symmetry_ by Marsden & Ratiu, p. 451) of a group whose generic coadjoint orbits are not embedded. If the coadjoint action is a proper action (in particular if $G$ is compact), then all orbits are embedded.

Comment: @AlexZorn: The inclusion maps of coadjoint orbits are not proper, unless your group is, say, compact. Think about G=SL(2,R) and orbits of nilpotent matrices.

Comment: @studiosus: The orbits of nilpotent matrices are {0}, and the set of 2x2 traceless matrices [a, b; c, -a] satisfying a^2 - bc = 0, minus {0}. The latter is not a closed submanifold but it is still a locally closed submanifold, and the inclusion is a topological embedding. Right? In contrast to say, the usual example of R acting on a torus via irrational shifts in which the orbits are not embeddings.

Comment: @JackLee: Thanks for the reference, I'll check it out.